# Unable to login to server using RDP after server left domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 which is a member of an AD domain.  I need to disjoin it from the domain and make it a stand-alone server.  I have local accounts on the server and can log into them just fine when the server is a member of the domain, but after switching the server to a workgroup instead of a domain member, I can no longer login to these very same local accounts via RDP - I just get **"This computer cannot connect to the remote computer."** This message comes up *after* the log-in prompt (which is successfully authenticated) and the prompt to accept the certificate from the remote machine.

There is nothing in the event logs indicating what is wrong.

The users are members of the Remote Desktop Users group.

The "Local Security Policy > Local Policies > User Rights Assignments > Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" is set to:

- Administrators
- Authenticated User
- Remote Desktop Users

I have no idea why RDP connections break as soon as the server is no longer a member of the domain - help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is remote desktop exception enabled for just domain network?

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -ano | findstr /i ":3389"` on the affected server?

Comment: @GregAskew 3389 is listening.  That is not the issue.

Comment: @BobVale How do I check this?

Comment: Maybe the RDP was enabled on that server as part of a Group Policy, which is no longer in effect when the server leaves the domain?

Comment: Have you specified the name of your server when you attempt to logon with rdp. ? Ex: servername\administrator

Comment: You will need to look at advanced firewall, incoming rules you will we a remote desktop rule. The private one is probably disabled

Comment: If the RDP clients are still members of the domain, do you have any of the RDP client policies set on the domain members? Example `Path` Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client `Setting` Configure server authentication for client

Comment: @BobVale I added an edit to the question, as this error occurs after the log-in prompt comes up for the remote connection. If this were the firewall that should prevent a log-in attempt.

Comment: @Mr.Q Yes, that eliminates it being a firewall issue.It could be a certificate revocation lookup problem, or accepted hash alogrithim - but you should get an error in the eventlog. Are you sure you get nothing in the eventlog on either client or server?

Comment: Make sure the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server Reg_DWord value called fDenyTSConnections is set to value = 0 (zero)